# multiple user management on SCDF

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am working on an academic project where i need to provide SCDF as a SaaS. So different users should be able to connect to their SCDF and access, deploy, and manage their streams and tasks. Of course, other users shouldn't access those private streams and tasks.
From my different readings i found that SCDF has some LDAP capabilities and i even found that a single user mode is used by default. However, from what i understood, the LDAP is used to authenticate servers and not users, and i am not sure if the user content separation exists.
If there is a user management, can you orient me or provide me with some relevant readings and material. Otherwise, can you give me tips on the "best" way to implement such an option.

Answer (score 0):

For multi user management, you can use `file` based authentication supported in SCDF.

Sample configuration would look like this:

`security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
    realm: Spring Cloud Data Flow
dataflow:
  security:
    authentication:
      file:
        enabled: true

        users:

          bob: bobspassword, ROLE_ADMIN

          alice: alicepwd, ROLE_VIEW, ROLE_CREATE`

Comment: thank you for your help, although it seems role definitions aren't supported in new SCDF versions. Also, I need to know if a users can access streams and tasks created by another user.

Comment: > although it seems role definitions aren't supported in new SCDF -- that must be a bug.  Please create an issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow with any useful information to debug.